# First time building interactive floor map

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a interesting task of building an interactive map for a family attraction company on their site. The idea is that people can click on a activity and it will show up on the map where it is located with some info in the dialog box. Also their has to be a option that people can click directly on the map on a building and that is show the same box with content in it.

This is new to me and I would like to have some one who can point me in the right direction on how I can build this or tools who can help me with this. I have look around and see a lot about HTML5 canvas but I was thinking if their a other way ( easy way ) for a beginner to build a interactive floor map.

Thanks all for your help.

Comment: Is this just a simple floor map of a building (like a blueprint), or when you say "click on the map and show where it is located" do you also include city,country,world maps ?

Comment: @sinanspd no, it is something like this: http://i59.tinypic.com/r9rjn5.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Guys thanks for your help, I've manage to build the map using Jquery which was easier than using HTML canvas. I have used a technique from Sam Dunn as foundation for my map and add my own functions on top of it. More about Sam Dunn way of making a interactive image you can read it here: http://buildinternet.com/2009/11/making-an-interactive-picture-with-jquery/

Thanks all for pointing me in the right direction. This post can be closed.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you can use a regular map, I would recommend [leaflet](http://leafletjs.com/), it is pretty lightweight map library.

I'll edit my answer if you provide some additional details. It really depends on if you need to input your own floor plan, or if you can use a map. And how complex this floor plan is.

Comment: This is the floor map that I need to use in the website.( http://i59.tinypic.com/r9rjn5.jpg ) And there will be a list of activities link outside this floor map that has to show a dialog box when click on the activities links.

Answer (score -1):

I created a very basic document that might help you get started, I add images within divs in html, position them in css and make them interactive using jquery and jquery ui.

html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.ui/1.8.10/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='scripts.js'></script>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css'/>
<link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='styles.css' />
</head>
<body>
<div id="building1"><img src="http://www.dundjinni.com/forums/uploads/dragonwolf/ACE_Shack_big_td_dgw-b.png" alt="building1" width="100px" height="200px"></div>
<div id="building2"><img src="http://www.dundjinni.com/forums/uploads/dragonwolf/ACE_Shack_big_td_dgw-b.png" alt="building2" width="100px" height="200px"></div>
<div id="building3"><img src="http://www.dundjinni.com/forums/uploads/dragonwolf/ACE_Shack_big_td_dgw-b.png" alt="building3" width="100px" height="200px"></div>
<div id="building4"><img src="http://www.dundjinni.com/forums/uploads/dragonwolf/ACE_Shack_big_td_dgw-b.png" alt="building4" width="100px" height="200px"></div>

 <!-- Text in the accordion when you click on the first building (Left top) -->
    <div id="information1">
        <h3>1Something</h3>
        <div>
        <p>1A bit of information.</p>
    </div>
        <h3>1Something more</h3>
        <div>
        <p>1A bit more information.</p>
    </div>
         <h3>1Something more, again.</h3>
        <div>
         <p>1A bit of extra information.</p>
    </div>
    </div>     

    <!-- Text in the accordion when you click on the second building (Right top) -->

    <div id="information2">
    <h3>2Something</h3>
        <div>
        <p>2A bit of information.</p>
    </div>
        <h3>2Something more</h3>
        <div>
        <p>2A bit more information.</p>
    </div>
         <h3>2Something more, again.</h3>
        <div>
         <p>2A bit of extra information.</p>
    </div></div>

    <!-- Text in the accordion when you click on the third building (Left bottom) -->

    <div id="information3">
    <h3>3Something</h3>
        <div>
        <p>3A bit of information.</p>
    </div>
        <h3>3Something more</h3>
        <div>
        <p>3A bit more information.</p>
    </div>
         <h3>3Something more, again.</h3>
        <div>
         <p>3A bit of extra information.</p>
    </div></div>

    <!-- Text in the accordion when you click on the fourth building (Right bottom) -->

    <div id="information4">
    <h3>4Something</h3>
        <div>
        <p>4A bit of information.</p>
    </div>
        <h3>4Something more</h3>
        <div>
        <p>4A bit more information.</p>
    </div>
         <h3>4Something more, again.</h3>
        <div>
         <p>4A bit of extra information.</p>
    </div></div>
</body>
</html>
```

css:

```
#building1 {
    position: fixed;
    left: 10px;
    top: 10px;
}

#building2 {
    position: fixed;
    left: 300px;
    top: 10px;
}

#building3 {
    position: fixed;
    left: 10px;
    top: 300px;
}

#building4 {
    position: fixed;
    left: 300px;
    top: 300px;
}

#information1 {
    position: fixed;
    left: 600px;
    top: 10px;
}

#information2 {
    position: fixed;
    left: 600px;
    top: 10px;
}

#information3 {
    position: fixed;
    left: 600px;
    top: 10px;
}

#information4 {
    position: fixed;
    left: 600px;
    top: 10px;
}
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#information1').hide();
$('#information2').hide();  /* Hide all the information accordions  */
$('#information3').hide();
$('#information4').hide();
$('#building1').click(function(){
$('#information2').hide();
$('#information3').hide();  /* Hide all the information accordions except the first one, that one will show if you click the first building */
$('#information4').hide();
$('#information1').show();
$('#information1').accordion();  /* simple menu when you use jquery ui */
});
$('#building2').click(function(){
$('#information1').hide();
$('#information3').hide();   /* Hide all the information accordions except the second one, that one will show if you click the second building */
$('#information4').hide();
$('#information2').show();
$('#information2').accordion();
});
$('#building3').click(function(){
$('#information1').hide();
$('#information2').hide();   /* Hide all the information accordions except the third one, that one will show if you click the third building */
$('#information4').hide();
$('#information3').show();
$('#information3').accordion();
});
$('#building4').click(function(){
$('#information1').hide();
$('#information2').hide();   /* Hide all the information accordions except the fourth one, that one will show if you click the fourth building */
$('#information3').hide();
$('#information4').show();
$('#information4').accordion();
});
});
```

Comment: Thanks! I'll give it a try and let you know how did it go.

Comment: This depends on a lot of hard-coding and a lot of duplicate code.... It will not be especially maintainable if you move  past 3 buildings.

Comment: Well, it's not meant for copy past or anything, I created this to show some easy jquery interaction which he can use, and help him get started.